# Is there a program to create gifs out of text?

Tags: graphics, converters, animated-gif

Is there any program that can convert a file into an animated gif by taking the bytes (whatever I see on an editor is seen) and producing them on frames? Im trying to change a large script I wrote into an image so that if I run it, it looks like as if the code is scrolling. I would use photoshop, if I knew how to use it. Even then, the code is really big, so I dont want to be doing it frame by frame.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you see on the editor screen is ... a screenfull, so why not a screen capture program like http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm

However, I suspect that you want to convert the entire file to a gif, since you talk of scrolling. Is that so?

If so, be aware that animated GIFs are limited to 8 frames, so you might want to convert to another movie format.

You could, for instance, Google for "text to MPEG". If nothing does it directly, get something that adds subtitles & make your video a solid white background *or match your webpage).

Maybe simpler is something like [this](http://a-scrolling-text-applet-now-free.sirius-computer-consultants-limited.qarchive.org/) ...

```
A Scrolling Text Applet - Now Free. - Provide an animated look and feel to your web pages. Scrolling Text is a Java applet that will automatically size itself to the available area given to it by the HTML form via the WIDTH and HEIGHT properties of the APPLET tag. There are many configurable features of this applet including title, colors, font size and style, border width and color, graphics, background images etc.

Configurable parameters including;

Background Color - Define your desired background color 

Title - If you want a stationary title then include this parameter 

Font Size and Style - All text can have it's own Font size and style 

Text Color - Specify the color of the text with this one 

Border Width and Color - If you require a border then define it with these 2 parameters 

Scroll Speed - Customise the Scroll Speed 

Display Time - Vary the Display time of each page 

This applet is easy to implement and configure and along with the example and help files you should have no trouble implementing your own customised Scrolling Text in your web pages. No understanding of java programming is required, everything is adjusted by parameters in the HTML tags.

Now FREE.
```

+1 for an interesting question.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that animated GIFs are limited to 8 frames? The samples on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) have far more than that.

Comment: +1 for correcting me. Maybe it used to be that way, long ago? Maybe I misremembered? Sorry for the misinformation